# SQL script to get information to add to the DB

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to create an swl script that will prompt the user for information that will be added to the database.  I am prompting the user for a date and a store name.  After the user enters the store name I want to run a query that will return a code associated with that store name and assign it to a variable.  When I run this script, after the user enters the store name, this is what happens:

```
Enter the date of the expense:01-01-13
Enter the store name for which the expense was against:MetEd
  12
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong as I am new to writing SQL scripts.  Below is my script file  I appreciate any help/tips.  Thank you.  P.S., I amusing sql plus / oracle.

```
ACCEPT EDate PROMPT 'Enter the date of the expense:';
ACCEPT StoreName PROMPT 'Enter the store name for which the expense was against:';

DECLARE
    v_StoreCode VARCHAR;
BEGIN
    SELECT CODE
    INTO v_StoreCode
    FROM STORE
    WHERE STORENAME = '&StoreName';
END;

INSERT INTO EXPMAST (ExpNum, EDate, StoreCode)
   VALUES(seq_EXPMAST.nextval, to_date('&EDate','mm-dd-yy'), 'v_StoreCode');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `12` is a line number, because you're being prompted for input.  SQL*Plus expects a `/` on a new line to execute an anonymous block.  Your script hasn't got that.  Hence the prompt.

You have other problems.  I presume you want to insert the retrieved value of CODE but right now you're inserting a string `'v_StoreCode'`.  So you need to remove those single quotes.

```
ACCEPT EDate PROMPT 'Enter the date of the expense:';
ACCEPT StoreName PROMPT 'Enter the store name for which the expense was against:';

DECLARE
    v_StoreCode VARCHAR;
BEGIN
    SELECT CODE
    INTO v_StoreCode
    FROM STORE
    WHERE STORENAME = '&StoreName';
END;
/

INSERT INTO EXPMAST (ExpNum, EDate, StoreCode)
   VALUES(seq_EXPMAST.nextval, to_date('&EDate','mm-dd-yy'), v_StoreCode);
```

---

In addition you could tidy up the code by using the INSERT ... SELECT construct:

```
ACCEPT EDate PROMPT 'Enter the date of the expense:';
ACCEPT StoreName PROMPT 'Enter the store name for which the expense was against:';

INSERT INTO EXPMAST (ExpNum, EDate, StoreCode)
   SELECT seq_EXPMAST.nextval, to_date('&EDate','mm-dd-yy'), CODE
   FROM STORE
    WHERE STORENAME = '&StoreName';
```